# How does each browser expose intermediary representation of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, interpreter

**Question:**

I've heard people use the terms dynamic compilation and interpretation interchangeably.  This isn't a question about semantics.

Obviously by the time the code hits the processor it is in some binary form.

How can I look at intermediate represenation?

For example, it is pretty easy to look at your C code in assembly by using compiler options.

Is there a similar way to do this with JavaScript?  I'm not sure what the intermediary representation would be called but here are some general references.

**Research**

- Interpreter ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29))
- Dynamic Compilation ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_compilation))
- Compilation ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler))

**Clarification:**

This question has nothing to do with minification.

Comment: If I may ask, why do you want to find a way to do this?

Comment: So, you mean optimization?

Comment: For V8, you can run `d8 --print_code` or `d8 --print_opt_code`

Comment: There is no one standard, universally agreed-upon internal representation for JavaScript and each JS engine interprets or compiles JS in its own way.  You are probably best off picking a nice JS engine like Rhino and checking the docs to see if it can do what you want it to do.

Comment: In what environment do you wish to do this? What makes you think the intermediate representation will always be available across JS implementations? There's no reason a JS engine would need to expose anything a person could look at; a JS engine may be implemented in any number of ways.

Comment: @templatetypedef - that comment seems like an answer to me :)

Comment: I would assume that each browser compiles Javascript source into some kind of internal tree-like data structure, or even possibly something resembling proprietary bytecode. In any case, it's in an in-memory format that probably does not make for easy viewing or decoding by humans.

Comment: Newer versions of Safari compile directly to "native machine code" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit#JavaScriptCore

Comment: Given there's lot of internal possible representations, what do you hope to learn by looking at a randomly chosen one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build V8 yourself by compiling the d8 shell, you can run `d8 --print_code` or `d8 --print_opt_code`. You probably want to output this data into a file.

Answer (score 1):

See if [these slides](http://moe-js.googlecode.com/git-history/HEAD/talks/jsconfeu2012/index.html?r=HEAD) from Vyacheslav Egorov's [mö.js](https://code.google.com/p/moe-js/) JSConf [talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8hVeKMD_oM) get you any closer to what you need.